# Hosted mobile web app to the app store?

Tags: mobile, cordova, app-store, mobile-website

I have a mobile web app hosted on a server currently. I would like to submit this to the Apple, Google, and Microsoft app stores, but all the PhoneGap samples involve packaging up all the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files and wrapping it. I want to make it even simplier by leaving the mobile web app hosted on the server and use PhoneGap only as an iframe to view the hosted app. That way, I can make updates that would propagate to all the devices without having to update through the app store. Also the main reason for me wanting to do this is because I have about 20GB's of audio and video files that I obviously can't packaging up into PhoneGap and place in the app store. Any help or advise would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: take a look at  https://m.uber.com and this is used in an uber app (as a URL). the app is same here. For larger files i would rcommedn to use seperation of concern here and have rest endpoints to fetch your audio and video file. you ca use nodejs for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you can't do that.

For one, like you said, PhoneGap needs the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files, they can't be hosted and still be packaged. Also, Apple does not allow you to make updates without going through them, it's one of their rules, so you would not be able to make updates like you asked. Last, I also know that if it is something that could work as just a mobile web app, then it will most likely get rejected when submitted. And I guarantee you that if you only put an iframe that links to your current app it will not be let through.

The whole point of PhoneGap is not let you put web apps into mobile app stores, it's to allow you to use such technologies as HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to build hybrid apps that also give you access native features through plugins.

It already sounds like you have something working and have no need for PhoneGap. Simply tell your users to add your site to their home screen, it will give you the power you're looking for to push updates without forcing your users to update through an app store.

Comment: So basically, you're saying this is not possible because Apple has rules that prevents this? The question is interesting and should be explored more. If there are no technical impediments, why not try and submit an app like this to the different app stores and see what gets through.

Comment: Does this still apply now in 2015? There have been no changes to the policy, it's not possible to get hosted web apps into the App Store?